# PlotLegends for parameter steps in ParametricNDSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, legending, publishing

Given:

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{y'[t] == a y[t], y[0] == 1}, 
  y, {t, 0, 10}, {a}]

Plot[Evaluate[Table[y[a][t] /. sol, {a, -1, 1, .1}]], {t, 0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

How can I make the legend show the correspondence of an individual curve to the corresponding parameter value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[Legended[y[a][t], a] /. sol, {a, -1, 1, .1}]]
  , {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[Callout[y[a][t], a] /. sol, {a, -1, 1, .1}]]
 , {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

**EDIT**

To answer the question in the comment, here are some ways to add the text "a=" at different locations. There are really a lot of possibilities to tune this layout, so I may miss something better :

```
Plot[Evaluate[
Table[Legended[y[a][t]
  , Row[{HoldForm[a], " = ", a}]] /. 
   sol, {a, -1, 1, .1}]], {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All,
PlotLegends -> 
  LineLegend[Expression, Automatic, LegendLabel -> "a = ..."]]
```

[image]

Comment: Cool ! But how to write not just numbers, but $a=...$

Comment: you want "a=..." repeated 20 times ? or only once somewhere ?

Comment: show both options , I will then decrease the plot and put the graph in order, I just want to understand the principle

Comment: See my Edit. I can't do more at the moment.

Comment: This is a good result, it suits me. Thank you so much for your help!